# How are domain directories created in weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Just wanted to know what files are responsible for creating the domain directories after the domain creation. After I create a domain in Weblogic, these directories are created automatically (see image for directories below). My true intention is to find a way to modify the heap size and thread pool size through a createDomain bat file instead of modifying the newly created config files located after the domain is created. I just want to know what file is responsible for creating the config file so that I can overwrite that to include the specific size of the heap size I wish to change. Thanks for the time

[Domain directories in Weblogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkp6V.png)

Comment: A domain can be created with the Configuration wizzard or WLST (scripting)
Updating servers' heap size can be done in the setDomainEnv.sh or setUserOverrides.sh script.
Other configuration can be set using the admin console or WLST for instance

Comment: How do you create your domain?  If using a wlst script then you could enhance that script to modify the setDomainEnv.cmd file after the domain creation.